# How to hide the tags “all, publish, thrash, draft, pending” for authors posts but not for the administrator?

Tags: dashboard

I had find the code below and it is hide the tags “all, publish, thrash, draft, pending” for authors posts BUT is also keep hiding the tags for administrator too !

```
function remove_edit_post_views( $views ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        unset($views['all']);       
        unset($views['publish']);       
        unset($views['trash']);
        unset($views['draft']);       
        unset($views['pending']);
        return $views;
    }
}    

add_action( 'views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views' );
```

How can be showing those tabs for administrator?

Any help is appreciated!

Sorry for my not good english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the $views for admins, thats why you don't see anyting.

EDIT: IMPORTANT, you are using a action but you need to use filter

```
function remove_edit_post_views ($views) {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        unset($views['all']);
        unset($views['publish']);
        unset($views['trash']);
        unset($views['draft']);
        unset($views['pending']);

        return $views;
    }

    return $views; // this is the missing piece
}

add_filter('views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views');
```

You can make it even shorter by doing this

```
function remove_edit_post_views ($views) {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) return [];
    return $views;
}

add_filter('views_edit-post', 'remove_edit_post_views');
```

Comment: Indeed the " return $views; " was the missing piece! . Thank you for your help!  ;)